# Starting a payara 5 has encountered

Tags: maven, jsf-2, glassfish, cdi, payara

I have build a very simple project of **hello world** in

> **Payara 5 (5.181)**
>   JSF 2.3
>   JDK 1.8
>   CDI 2.0
>   Maven

and encountered a problem

> *Unable to start server due following issues: Launch process failed with exit code 1*

in console it throws an error of :

> **Error: Could not find or load main class server\payara5\glassfish.lib.grizzly-npn-bootstrap.jar**

[[PIC] Payara 5 Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AiVj.png)

Comment: So if you make a small hello world test app without jsf and cdi, not created with maven,  e.g. just a simple jsp page, it **does** work?

Comment: i tried now i think payara have some bug incompatibility with eclipse that's why it is not blank running (not starting) without any project

Comment: Have you used [Payara Tools for Eclipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/payara-tools)? GlassFish tools don't work with Payara 5

Comment: yes i am using payara Tools for Eclipse but still didn't get any solution

Comment: Perhaps [try downloading Payara 5.182](https://www.payara.fish/all_downloads). That is working for me with Payara Tools for Eclipse + Eclipse Photon + jdk1.8.0_172. Also see ["Payara Tools Unlocks Eclipse For Payara 5"](https://blog.payara.fish/payara-tools-unlocks-eclipse-for-payara-5) which mentions an issue with 5.181.

Answer (score 8):

It seems that the Payara Tools for Eclipse suffer by several bugs that may cause this. In my case, the following workarounds helped:

- The Payara installation path *should not* contain spaces (e.g. Program Files\Payara)
- It seems that only Java 8 is supported at the time
- Open the `domain.xml` configuration file for the domain you are trying to start (typically *payara_install_path*/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/domain1.xml) and search for "Xbootclasspath". You should find a couple of lines like

      `<jvm-options>[1.8.0|1.8.0u120]-Xbootclasspath/p:${com.sun.aas.installRoot}/lib/grizzly-npn-bootstrap-1.6.jar</jvm-options>
      <jvm-options>[1.8.0u121|1.8.0u160]-Xbootclasspath/p:${com.sun.aas.installRoot}/lib/grizzly-npn-bootstrap-1.7.jar</jvm-options>
      <jvm-options>[1.8.0u161|1.8.0u190]-Xbootclasspath/p:${com.sun.aas.installRoot}/lib/grizzly-npn-bootstrap-1.8.jar</jvm-options>
      <jvm-options>[1.8.0u191|1.8.0u500]-Xbootclasspath/p:${com.sun.aas.installRoot}/lib/grizzly-npn-bootstrap-1.8.1.jar</jvm-options>`

  Depending of your installed Java version (try running `java --version`) and choose the appropriate line (most likely the last one). Remove the remaining lines and remove the [...] part at the beginning of the chosen line so you will get something like

  `<jvm-options>-Xbootclasspath/p:${com.sun.aas.installRoot}/lib/grizzly-npn-bootstrap-1.8.1.jar</jvm-options>`

After this, the tools seem to start normally.

Answer (score 5):

The Problem is with Java version. The **grizzly-npn-bootstrap-1.8.1.jar** Jar is placed in bootclasspath, thats why it requires proper java version to start payara server. So remove unnecessary bootstrap jar from **domain.xml**.

In Windows:

1) Go To ---C:\Users\xxxx\payara5\glassfish\domains\domain1\config\domain.xml

2) According to my java verson(**java version "1.8.0_191"**) I deleted the following lines from domain.xml. So delete according to your java version.

```
<jvm-options>[1.8.0|1.8.0u120]-Xbootclasspath/p:${com.sun.aas.installRoot}/lib/grizzly-npn-bootstrap-1.6.jar</jvm-options>
        <jvm-options>[1.8.0u121|1.8.0u160]-Xbootclasspath/p:${com.sun.aas.installRoot}/lib/grizzly-npn-bootstrap-1.7.jar</jvm-options>
        <jvm-options>[1.8.0u161|1.8.0u190]-Xbootclasspath/p:${com.sun.aas.installRoot}/lib/grizzly-npn-bootstrap-1.8.jar</jvm-options>
```

3) Remove this **[1.8.0u191|1.8.0u500]** part from **jvm-options** & Edit the line in your domain.xml(w.r.t java -version) as shown below

```
<jvm-options>-Xbootclasspath/p:${com.sun.aas.installRoot}/lib/grizzly-npn-bootstrap-1.8.1.jar</jvm-options>
```

4) restart your server.

Answer (score 1):

As Radkovo said, "The Payara installation path should not contain spaces (e.g. Program Files\Payara)", so I moved the Payara to the Documents folder.
Problem solved!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).